# accept a single character with a default value? read-char with default value?

Tags: read-char

How can I read a single input from minibuffer ,
and provide a default value at the same time so he can just enter to accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```lisp
(string-to-char
  (read-string "Char (or the first char of your input string): "
               nil nil
               ;; Default:
               ""))
```

If you use functions like `read-char`, it will be difficult to distinguish between the default value and the keystroke of `<return>`.  (You cannot use `C-q`, because it just issues the char `?\C-q`.

Comment: “*the keystroke of `<return>`*” -- I mean `?\C-m`.